# When using scratch docker container, get this error message ""cannot unmarshal DNS message"

Tags: docker, go, dns

I am trying to run a scratch docker container on my local from my go code. The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM golang:1.11.4 as builder


WORKDIR /app

ADD . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64  GOARM=7 make

FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /app/myprogram .
```

In my code I try to connect to mongodb using the following url `mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@my-staging-vki7g.gcp.mongodb.net`

I can connect to this mongodb perfectly fine on my local  mongoshell.
However, when I run my scracth container, I get the following error

```
error parsing uri (mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@my-staging-vki7g.gcp.mongodb.net): lookup provendb-staging-vki7g.gcp.mongodb.net on 192.168.65.1:53: cannot unmarshal DNS message
```

Are there any dependencies that need to be added?

Comment: From Scratch means no operating system.
Normally it's used to configure the base operating system where you will actually add necessary dependencies and Application binaries.

Comment: yes, are there any explicit dependencies I need to copy from `non-scratch` to `scratch`?

Comment: If you use scratch then you have to copy all the operating system related binaries.
Take an example how alpine image is build : https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/d39bc7743955e37ac15e8d82af14410c0b8b9a03/versions/library-3.8/x86_64/Dockerfile

Is there any specific reason why you want to use scratch as the base image ?

From my opinion you should use : alpine instead of scratch

Comment: @fly2matrix I disagree.  One of the great things about Go in the Cloud is how the binaries can be added to a scratch container for a very small, secure container without any of the vulnerabilities that may be brought in with an OS so whenever possible I think Go binaries should use `FROM scratch`.  That said, I'm afraid I don't know how to answer your question @user3288346!

Comment: Thanks @Lain , I'll verify and give a response after trying something on GoLang.

Comment: Thanks @IainDuncan for correcting me , I'll check the real issue and give a response.
https://www.cloudreach.com/blog/containerize-this-golang-dockerfiles/

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss some build flags. Also not sure why you would want to compile as arm for a docker container.

I wrote a blog post on building a Docker image like you do here. That might help you resolve your issue.

https://marcofranssen.nl/docker-tips-and-tricks-for-your-go-projects/